# Quit thread from inside the thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

If got the following scenario:

1. Thread0 is running code which calls other components.
2. Component0 gets called of Thread0 and fires an event.
3. The Eventhandler tries to stop the thread0 by setting a stopflag
4. Now I usually would join Thread0 to wait until has cleaned up all stuff and has finished. But if I would do that, I would cause a deadlock. So lets say, I just set the flag to exit finish Thread0 to true and return to the Eventhandler of Component0 event.
5. The next line of the Eventhandler tries disposes resources Thread0 is using. Remember: Thread0 is still running, because I can't wait on it because the eventhandler which tries to stop Thread0 is gets executed in the context of Thread0.
6. Now the Eventhandler is finished and Thread0 tries to use the previously disposed resources > that causes unknown behaviour.

Currently I am asking for flag right after processing all components whether it got disposed. If it got disposed, I break the quit the thread.

Is there a better pattern to handle such complicated behaviours.

Comment: Why are you not just disposing of the resources Thread0 uses at the end of Thread0's main loop (after the flag has already been found to indicate the thread should stop)?

Comment: I didnt understand your flow.. its not written well, but if you have member flag, consider marking it as volatile.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are doing, but in my opinion the cleanest way to abort a thread is to throw an exception and let that bubble up to the outer scope where it should get logged, or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Can you post an sscce? http://sscce.org/

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - yeah, call Thread.Abort() in the event hander, perform any cleanup in a 'finally' block.

Answer (score 1):

> The next line of the Eventhandler tries disposes resources Thread0 is using

This is your problem right there. You are trying to release resources from an external scope, this often leads to trouble.

Do you have a limitation that does not allow you to deterministically release resources used by thread0 at the end of it's execution? If so, please post some more explanations. Maybe a simplified code sample.

Also, the distinction between thread and event handler is not appropriate here. From your description, I understand that the code of the event handler executes on thread0. So you should be talking about 2 or more components executing one after the other when at some point, one of them does something that trips the one's that run right after it, on the same thread.

Comment: the problem is that my code is part of a library. So I don't know what the user will do with the library.

Comment: @thefiloe, I do not understand.